# Machine Learning (Python) - Unusual Accuracy 99.9%

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, prediction

I have recently built a predictive model(Logistic Regression) on this dataset from kaggle (Shape : 1646801, 150) . However, I get very unusual accuracy of 99.9% after simple preprocessing. Data: https://www.kaggle.com/wordsforthewise/lending-club

[image]

Step tooked :

- **Mapped** different **loan_status** *('Fully_Paid', 'Default', 'Charged Off')* to **default** *(0,1)*
- Find count of **null** value for each column, **remove** **column** if **null > 10000**
- Remove rows with other null value, the shape is left (814392, 51)
- Remove grade and mapped **sub_grade** *('A1', 'A3')* as **integer** *(0, 2)*
- **One-Hot Encoding**
- **Modeling** with Logistic Regression ***(Class label ratio is 1:4)***

For the modeling part, I first use train-test split and get 99.9% accuracy. I also checked the confusion matrix and the TP and TN are both high. I have also checked the feature importance and the features seems normal and doesn't seem like any feature is clearly outperforming other feature. I have also tried 5-fold and 10-fold cross-validation, the accuracy is still very high.

Below is the modeling code, I will show any pre-processing code if it seems to help in solving the problem.

```
    y = df2[['default']].values.ravel()
    X = df2.drop(columns = 'default').values
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)
    features = df2.drop(columns = 'default').columns.tolist()
    LR = model.LogisticRegression()
    LR.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = LR.predict(X_test)
    print('Accuracy : ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print('\n', metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    print('Confusion Matrix')
    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

What seems to be the problem? Is that any part I did wrongly?

Comment: How many classes do you have? and what is there ratio

Comment: 2 classes and 4:1 ratio

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful how you split the data, and what columns you use. It seems that there is a small [time series](https://www.kaggleusercontent.com/kf/2746071/eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..sHyGKUhYwSJOcmV1HpDu8A.7ZBKUfn9tdXj8oZBBZK_Aqu1h5IcH0WGA1e2fxlde4CCKa23BH3vL5iBsb1zwLPSXhF79dGgjxiSDKQFaNKjFRtuCDG-Bnu5SLBX4Z22ddrBWUbW3u6nAjZw1dwihe0beydJmfVs54lS7EctrLzoFDFSA42ETTNVY3tX0EiJofY.pRmj-4DNAWf3OQAdupduWA/__results__.html#Time-series) in the data. That means for one customer there are probably multiple data points. I would make sure to remove id fields.

If that still does not help, partition the data by customer and seperate the customers into training/test.

Then look out for fields that are highly correlated to the loan_status. Some could be related to the fact that the person is already in default. Instead, you could predict the default status of a customer from his data in the previous month.

You are also removing a lot of rows - this could be ok but you could also be selecting for cases that are easy to classify.

Comment: Each customer has only one unique record, it is not time series. Also as mentioned, the feature importance looks normal enough, even if I remove some important features, the accuracy is still high.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong - `scores = cross_val_score(LR, X, y, cv=5)`. You are exposing your model to `X_test` and `y_test` in the cross-validation step. Your model can never see your test data during training or cross validation.  Instead you could do `scores = cross_val_score(LR, X_train, y_train, cv=5)` and make prediction on your test set.

Another approach could be to use validation set approach instead of k-fold CV.

Check out `GridSearchCV` of scikit-learn.